# How to configure the docker snap to accept a private registry certificate?

Tags: snap, docker

When installing docker as a snap I am not able to tell it to accept a private registry certificate.
The only time it appeared to at lest consider the certificate was when I put it in

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/<my registry host and port>/ca.pem
```

In that case however I got

```
Error response from daemon: open /etc/docker/certs.d/<my registry host and port>: permission denied
```

This holds true even if I give that directory 777 permissions.
The reason I put the certificate in that directory is that the snap logs for docker showed it looks for it there.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that from what I've seen, it is expecting .crt files rather than .pem files. That being said, did you ever find a full solution to this? I am facing precisely the same issue (only I'm using .crts).

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue and, after poking around a bit, found the solution.
You need to:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/snap/docker/certs.d/registryhost:port/
sudo cp your.crt /var/snap/docker/certs.d/registryhost:port/
sudo snap restart docker
```

Then log in to your registry via:

```
docker login registryhost:port
```

You should be able to push and pull images from your registry. Let me know if this works for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu the correct path is `/var/snap/docker/~current/etc/docker/certs.d`